# Conditions for creating a void homeomorphic to $n$-cube or to $n$-orthoplex within a discrete manifold

Tags: simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

Assume an $n$-dimensional discrete manifold $M$ ($n$-dimensional simplicial complex in which each ($n-1$)-simplex has exactly two adjacent $n$-simplices or only one if it is on a boundary of $M$) comprising a large number of $n$-simplices.

What is the minimum number of $1$-simplices one needs to remove from $M$ in order to create $n$-dimensional void within $M$ which void would be homeomorphic to $n$-cube or to $n$-orthoplex?

For $2$-manifold a void homeomorphic both to $2$-cube and $2$-orthoplex can be created by removing one $1$-simplex not on the boundary of $M$.

A void homeomorphic to $3$-cube can be created in $3$-manifold by removing one $3$-simplex, or specifically by removing six $1$-simplices on each $2$-face of this newly formed cube that defined this removed tetrahedron (tet in cube). This also result in creation of six quadrilateral pyramids on each face of the cube.

How about $4$-cube?

Are there any general formulas for this problem?

Comment: Your definition of a (closed) $n$-manifold as one in which each $(n-1)$-simplex has exactly $2$ neighboring $n$-simplices isn't the usual one -- that's a pseudo-manifold.

Comment: I took this definition (or rather a consequence of this definition) from http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/DKT05.pdf (3.1.5 on p. 5). But indeed -that would be a pseudo-manifold. Thank you.

Comment: To be fair to Mathieu (an old friend, and someone I'd have expected to not make this error, given his French mathematics education), you transcribed it unfaithfully: they wrote (roughly) "for each simplex, the union of all the incident $n$-simplices forms an $n$-dimensional ball ...", but this includes $n-2, n-3, \ldots, 0$-simplices as well as $(n-1)$-simplices; if you merely place the condition on codimension-1 simplices, you get a pseudomanifold. If you place it on all simplices, you get (after some work) the traditional definition of a manifold.

Comment: I think that if we assume that the number of $n$-simplices of $M$ is large, we may avoid pseudo-manifold issues.

Comment: I believe that you're mistaken --- I think the problem is that the $n$-simplices around a single vertex may join together to form something that's not actually a ball around that simplex. But it's been a very long time since I looked closely at this.

Comment: That's true. But then you would have more than one void or a void having vertex/vertices lying on the external boundary of the manifold. My point is to exclude such _pseudo_ voids.

Comment: My point is that you might have the star of a vertex $v$ be a manifold-with-boundary whose boundary -- the *link* of the vertex, the set of $(n-1)$-faces of the sub-simplices not containing $v$ -- is not topologically an $(n-1)$-sphere as you expected, but is instead something that is rather similar to an $(n-1)$-sphere, but in fact not homeomorphic/diffeomorphic/whatever-morphic depending on the category you're in. In particular, the cells around $v$ not forming a topological ball is *not* necessarily the same as "$v$ ends up on the boundary."

Comment: I would like to avoid dwelling into definitions of regular- or pseudo-manifolds. I exclude them following the comment of the Definition 2.3.8 of Hirani, A. N. 2003. Discrete Exterior Calculus. PhD thesis, Cal-tech. It’s not important to me to consider such possibly degenerate or borderline cases.

Comment: "Degenerate or borderline" is in the eye of the beholder. If you're willing to exclude degenerate cases, why not just say "in all cases the answer is whatever I want it to be, and the cases where it's not are degenerate and I'm ignoring them"? Unless you can phrase your question unambiguously, you're not likely to interest a lot of mathematicians in trying to guess an answer that'll meet with your hidden definition of "degenerate/borderline".